# Count number of unique combinations of two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet of statistics from sports games over a season, for different leagues - each row holds a single event that happened in a game, such as a penalty. There are many rows of events for each individual game. One of the columns is the league, another is the home team and another is the away team. How can I count the total number of games in a given league? In other words, I would need to count the number of unique pairs of strings from Home and Away, where League = "Ligue 1".

[image]

**EDIT**

I have tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIFS(E2:E81078,"Ligue 1",F2:F81078,F2:F81078,G2:G81078,G2:G81078)))
```

which returns a `DIV/0` error (it does work if I dont include the column E = "Ligue 1" criteria).

Comment: In the events, are things like the start of the game recorded?

Comment: No, there is a separate sheet for different types of events, this sheet just has all of the free kicks, for example

Comment: Would you consider using a pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to your formula but deals with the division by zero

```
=SUM(IFERROR((1/COUNTIFS(E2:E81078,"Ligue 1",F2:F81078,F2:F81078,G2:G81078,G2:G81078)),0))
```

Enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If done correctly you will see `{}` around the formula

Try not to use ranges that are bigger than your data because it will slow these kind of formulas down significantly

**Update**

This might also work if your data is ordered the way you show in your question. It counts the number of times the home team changes in `Ligue 1` data :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F3:F81079<>F2:F81078)*(E2:E81078="Ligue 1"))
```

Note that the ranges in column `F` are offset by one row

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Pivot Table.

Add a "helper" column where you concatenate the two teams, preferably with a delimiter in between, eg:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2, "|", C2)
```

Use, for example `Teams` for the column header

Then, Insert ► Pivot Table and be sure to select to `Add to Data Model`

[image]

This adds the option for `Distinct Counts` to the Values Settings

Then Drag "league" to the Rows area, "Teams" to the Values area, and select Distinct Count for the Value Setting

[image]

You might get a table similar to below, which you can format in many different ways:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[EXCEL SCREENSHOT`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$7,B1:B7,$C$1:$C$7,C1:C7))`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJqYJ.png)

TRY THIS =SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$7,B1:B7,$C$1:$C$7,C1:C7))